# Message = "Operation failed. The index entry of length 904 bytes for the index 'IX_companyinfo_exhibition' exceeds the maximum length of 900 bytes."

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I am unable to save details with some emailids. I am getting this error

> The index entry of length 904 bytes for the index 'IX_companyinfo_exhibition' exceeds the maximum length of 900 bytes.

When I entered the following emailsids, it's not getting saved:

```
info@combilift.com
marketing@hildaautomation.in
info@pakona.com
info@himedialabs.com
info.lho@liebherr.com
```

During debugging,in catch block, I found that I got this error:

> The index entry of length 904 bytes for the index 'IX_companyinfo_exhibition' exceeds the maximum length of 900 bytes.

Stored Procedure:

```
USE [expogroupdb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertManuallyUsingXmlExhibitorListNew]    Script Date: 2/20/2018 9:49:42 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertManuallyUsingXmlExhibitorListNew] 
    
@XML_TRANSACTIONDETAILS nText,
    @exhibitor nvarchar(100)
AS
DECLARE @docHandle int

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @exbitionID nvarchar(100)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @XML_TRANSACTIONDETAILS


-- CREATE TEMP TABLE

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    maxid nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    companyname nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   NULL,
    email nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    website nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    country bigint  NULL,
    contactperson nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    telphone nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    mobile nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    fax nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    region bigint  NULL,
    status bigint  NULL,
    username bigint  NULL,
    date datetime  NULL,
    category bigint  NULL,
    urlorcatalog nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    address nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    lastupdatedby bigint NULL,
    designation nvarchar(100) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    products nvarchar(400) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    comment nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
) 
-- Create Table to save Duplicates
CREATE TABLE #DuplTempTable
(
    maxid nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    ID bigint ,
    Dataid nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    companyname nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS   NULL,
    email nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    website nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    country bigint  NULL,
    contactperson nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    telphone nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    mobile nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    fax nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    region bigint  NULL,
    status bigint  NULL,
    username bigint  NULL,
    date datetime  NULL,
    category bigint  NULL,
    urlorcatalog nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    address nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  NULL,
    lastupdatedby bigint NULL,
    designation nvarchar(100) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    products nvarchar(400) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    comment nvarchar(200) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
)  
--  INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE DETAILS OF EMAIL 

INSERT INTO #TempTable
                (
                   maxid,companyname,email,website,country,contactperson,telphone,mobile,fax,region,status,username,date,category,urlorcatalog,address,lastupdatedby,designation,products,comment
                )

 SELECT
             data.maxid,data.companyname,data.email,data.website,data.country,data.contactperson,data.telphone,data.mobile,data.fax,data.region,data.status,data.username,GETDATE(),data.category,data.urlorcatalog,data.address,data.username,data.designation,data.products,data.comment

     FROM OPENXML(@docHandle,N'master/TRANSACTION',3)

              WITH
              (
               companyname nvarchar(200),
                website nvarchar(200),
                country bigint ,
                contactperson nvarchar(200),
                telphone nvarchar(200),
                mobile nvarchar(200),
                fax nvarchar(200),
                region bigint,
                status bigint,
                username bigint,                
                category bigint,
                urlorcatalog nvarchar(200),
                email nvarchar(200),                
                maxid nvarchar(200),
                address nvarchar(200),
                designation nvarchar(100), 
                products nvarchar(400) ,
                comment nvarchar(200)        
              ) as data

--  INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE DETAILS OF EMAIL1 

INSERT INTO #TempTable
                (
                   maxid,companyname,email,website,country,contactperson,telphone,mobile,fax,region,status,username,date,category,urlorcatalog,address,lastupdatedby,designation,products,comment
                )

 SELECT
             data.maxid,data.companyname,data.email1,data.website,data.country,data.contactperson,data.telphone,data.mobile,data.fax,data.region,data.status,data.username,GETDATE(),data.category,data.urlorcatalog,data.address,data.username,data.designation,data.products,data.comment

     FROM OPENXML(@docHandle,N'master/TRANSACTION',3)

              WITH
              (
               companyname nvarchar(200),
                website nvarchar(200),
                country bigint ,
                contactperson nvarchar(200),
                telphone nvarchar(200),
                mobile nvarchar(200),
                fax nvarchar(200),
                region bigint,
                status bigint,
                username bigint,                
                category bigint,
                urlorcatalog nvarchar(200),
                email1 nvarchar(200),               
                maxid nvarchar(200),
                dataentrytype nvarchar(200),
                lastupdatedby nvarchar(200),
                address nvarchar(200),
                designation nvarchar(100),
                products nvarchar(400),             
               comment nvarchar(200)  
              ) as data
            WHERE data.email1 !=''


--  INSERT INTO TEMP TABLE DETAILS OF EMAIL2 

INSERT INTO #TempTable
                (
                   maxid,companyname,email,website,country,contactperson,telphone,mobile,fax,region,status,username,date,category,urlorcatalog,address,lastupdatedby,designation,products,comment
                )

 SELECT
             data.maxid,data.companyname,data.email2,data.website,data.country,data.contactperson,data.telphone,data.mobile,data.fax,data.region,data.status,data.username,GETDATE(),data.category,data.urlorcatalog,data.address,data.username,data.designation,data.products,data.comment

     FROM OPENXML(@docHandle,N'master/TRANSACTION',3)

              WITH
              (
               companyname nvarchar(200),
                website nvarchar(200),
                country bigint ,
                contactperson nvarchar(200),
                telphone nvarchar(200),
                mobile nvarchar(200),
                fax nvarchar(200),
                region bigint,
                status bigint,
                username bigint,
                category bigint,
                urlorcatalog nvarchar(200),
                email2 nvarchar(200),
                maxid nvarchar(200),                
                address nvarchar(200),
                designation nvarchar(100),
                products nvarchar(400),
                comment nvarchar(200)               
              ) as data

            WHERE data.email2 !=''


--**********************UPDATE TEMP TABLE IF COUNTRY AND REGION IS NULL********************

UPDATE #TempTable 
SET
country=1
WHERE  country=0

UPDATE #TempTable 
SET
region=2
WHERE  region=0

-- CODE TO COUNT  DUPLICATES EMAILS

SELECT
 COUNT
( email)
                                        
FROM
    #TempTable T
                                        
        WHERE 
              T.email !=''
        AND 
         EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=T.email)

--insert into #DuplTempTable
INSERT INTO #DuplTempTable
                (
                   ID,Dataid,companyname,email,website,country,contactperson,telphone,mobile,fax,region,status,username,date,category,urlorcatalog,address,lastupdatedby,designation,products,comment
                )

 select ID,COMPANY.Dataid,TEMP1.companyname,email,TEMP1.website,TEMP1.country,TEMP1.contactperson,TEMP1.telphone,TEMP1.mobile,TEMP1.fax,TEMP1.region,TEMP1.status,TEMP1.username,TEMP1.date,TEMP1.category,TEMP1.urlorcatalog,TEMP1.address,TEMP1.lastupdatedby,TEMP1.designation,TEMP1.products,TEMP1.comment

from

        (   
            SELECT Email.Email,Email.dataId, tmp.companyname,tmp.website,tmp.country,tmp.contactperson,tmp.telphone,tmp.mobile,tmp.fax,tmp.region,tmp.status,tmp.username,tmp.date,tmp.category,tmp.urlorcatalog,tmp.address,tmp.lastupdatedby,tmp.designation,tmp.products,tmp.comment,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber'
        
            FROM #TempTable tmp 
            Inner JOIN emailinfo Email ON tmp.email =Email.email            
                                        
            WHERE 
              tmp.email !=''        
            
        )AS TEMP1

    Inner JOIN dbo.companyinfo COMPANY ON TEMP1.DataID =COMPANY.dataId  -- check this move this insd . email.dataid

    WHERE

    TEMP1.RowNumber =1 
    
    

--  TRANSACTION BEGINS HERE


BEGIN TRANSACTION

----------------------  EXHIBITOR LIST   ------------------------------------

    IF  EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                FROM    exibitions
                WHERE   exhibitiorlist=@exhibitor ) 

        BEGIN

        SELECT @exbitionID = EID FROM  exibitions WHERE exhibitiorlist=@exhibitor

        end

    ELSE

        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO exibitions  VALUES (@exhibitor)
            
            SET @exbitionID = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

        END
-------------  UPADATE COMPANY INFO IF EMAIL EXIST  ------------------------------------

--Akshata changes start
--select '#DuplTempTable',* from #DuplTempTable -- Akshata only for checking.
update cmp
 
 set cmp.lastupdatedby=dupl.lastupdatedby,cmp.lastupdateddate=dupl.date,cmp.category=case when cmp.status!=1 and cmp.status!=2 and cmp.status!=13 and cmp.status!=17 then dupl.category else cmp.category end,
 cmp.status=case when cmp.status!=1 and cmp.status < 6 and dupl.status < cmp.status then dupl.status else cmp.status end,
 cmp.comment=case when cmp.comment!='' And cmp.comment!=dupl.comment and (dupl.comment!='' OR dupl.comment!=null)  then COALESCE(cmp.comment + '/', '') + dupl.comment when (dupl.comment='' OR dupl.comment=null) then cmp.comment else dupl.comment end,
 cmp.exblist=COALESCE(cmp.exblist + ',', '') + @exbitionID
 from companyinfo cmp
inner join #DuplTempTable dupl on cmp.ID=dupl.ID 
IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END

update cmp
 
 set cmp.companyname=case when cmp.companyname='' or cmp.companyname=null then dupl.companyname else cmp.companyname end ,
 cmp.website= case when cmp.website='' OR cmp.website IS NULL then dupl.website else cmp.website end ,
 cmp.contactperson= case when cmp.contactperson='' OR cmp.contactperson IS NULL then dupl.contactperson else cmp.contactperson end,cmp.country = case when cmp.country=1 OR cmp.country IS NULL then dupl.country else cmp.country end,
 cmp.telphone=case when cmp.telphone='' OR cmp.telphone IS NULL then dupl.telphone else cmp.telphone end,cmp.mobile= case when cmp.mobile='' OR cmp.mobile IS NULL then dupl.mobile else cmp.mobile end ,
 cmp.fax= case when cmp.fax='' OR cmp.fax IS NULL then dupl.fax else cmp.fax end, cmp.region= case when cmp.region=2 OR cmp.region IS NULL then dupl.region else cmp.region end,
 cmp.address= case when cmp.address='' OR cmp.address IS NULL then dupl.address else cmp.address end,cmp.designation= case when cmp.designation='' OR cmp.designation IS NULL then dupl.designation else cmp.designation end,
 cmp.products= case when cmp.products='' OR cmp.products IS NULL then dupl.products else cmp.products end
 from companyinfo cmp
inner join #DuplTempTable dupl on cmp.ID=dupl.ID 

--select cmp.* from #DuplTempTable dpl inner join  companyinfo cmp
--on dpl.ID=cmp.id


IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END
--akshata changes end




--  ************INSERT INTO PRIMARY  TABLE(companyinfo)*************


INSERT INTO dbo.companyinfo
                (
                  dataId,companyname,website,country,contactperson,telphone,mobile,fax,region,status,userid,date,category,urlorcatalog,dataentrytype,address,exblist,designation,products,comment
              )


SELECT
                          T1.maxid,T1.companyname,T1.website,T1.country,T1.contactperson,T1.telphone,T1.mobile,T1.fax,T1.region,T1.status,T1.username,T1.date,T1.category,T1.urlorcatalog,'MANUAL',T1.address,@exbitionID,T1.designation,T1.products,T1.comment                 

                        FROM
                        (   
                            SELECT tmpdata.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY maxid ORDER BY maxid ) AS 'RowNumber'
                            FROM 
                            (
                            
                                        SELECT
                                                *
                                        
                                        FROM
                                        (
                                                SELECT tmp.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber1'
                                                FROM #TempTable tmp 
            --                                      LEFT OUTER JOIN emailinfo Email ON tmp.email=Email.email
                                        )AS T 
                                        
                                        WHERE T.RowNumber1=1
                                        AND  T.email !=''
                                        AND 
                                        NOT EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=T.email)


                             )tmpdata
            

                        )AS T1

                        WHERE 
                    T1.email !=''  AND

                    T1.RowNumber=1

IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END


--  ************INSERT INTO SECONDARY TABLE*************


INSERT INTO emailinfo
        ( 
            DataID,email
            )
SELECT
        T.maxid,T.email

FROM
(
        SELECT tmp.maxid,tmp.email, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.email ORDER BY tmp.email ) AS 'RowNumber'
        FROM #TempTable tmp 
            --LEFT OUTER JOIN emailinfo Email ON tmp.email=Email.email
)AS T 

WHERE T.RowNumber=1
AND  T.email !=''
AND 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT  emailinfo.email FROM dbo.emailinfo WHERE email=T.email)   

 IF @@ERROR<>0 BEGIN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION RETURN -101 END



COMMIT TRANSACTION

DROP TABLE #TempTable
DROP TABLE #DuplTempTable

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle
```

Is there any changes needed in stored procedure for email? I didn't tried anything much for this issue as I didn't got the meaning of this error only. I searched the web and the only thing I got is to modify the column.

I am beginner in C# and dealing with the stored procedure for the first time.

Comment: hi @user2705620....kindly check this link....https://ibb.co/h5rFsc

Comment: i added a general answer which you can check below, what i need to see is the keys used and the included columns used for IX_companyinfo_exhibition although you dont have to give it to me as you can check it yourself, by following my tips below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you provide the details of

> IX_companyinfo_exhibition

In a table with a **nonclustered** index with included columns, the total size of the index key columns is restricted to [900 bytes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx).

I think you are using companyinfo (which i suppose is varchar) or other fields that are big as an index key or an included column in your index IX_companyinfo_exhibition, this should not be used as an index as it is big and it is not a good index key nor an included column (due to its size). you can view it in your indexes in the table, the error pertains to the key used in one of the created index in the table and not an error in the stored procedure.

Just check your indexes and refrain/remove from using large fields(varchar, nvarchar,etc etc.) as an index key or included column. I would also suggest for you to read abit more about indexes and what are the best fields to uses as a proper index, because creating an incorrect index/too many index may do harm in your system than do more good.

you may check this as your [preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107132/what-columns-generally-make-good-indexes).

Comment: Hi you only showed me the list of indexes, you need to check the index keys and included columns inside the list of those indexes. you may edit/check the properties of the index that provides problem.

Comment: based on your screenshot what do you see? if you are going to re-read my answer youll know what causes the error based on your screenshot.

Comment: i have to reduce the size from 1200 to 900

Comment: no, you need to remove the column, you cant modify the column, you need to learn and identify yourself if that index is useful or not, if it is not useful, might aswell remove it.

Comment: hi sir...this error is only because of this column na....exblist(nvarchar(600),null)...i still dint got the connection of this column and inserting the details(emailsids)...

Comment: i removed the index...so i shd remove the column as well..?

Comment: i removed that column..but it still gives the same error

Comment: still dint got the solution