# How to resolve the error "The index entry of length 904 bytes for the index 'IX_companyinfo_exhibition' exceeds the maximum length of 900 bytes."

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i am getting the error as:

> "The index entry of length 904 bytes for the index 'IX_companyinfo_exhibition' exceeds the maximum length of 900 bytes".

`exblist nvarchar(600)`,i changed this to `nvarchar(450)`.i dropped the index ie.`IX_companyinfo_exhibition`.

i tried everything.even i used this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_companyinfo_exhibition ON dbo.companyinfo(exblist) include(companyname,website,country,contactperson,telphone)
```

i dont know whats wrong with this.still i am getting the same error.

[image]

[image]

[image: SP_helpindex for table companyinfo]

Comment: Good background info here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Could I suggest changing the length to 448?  I am guessing that will give you back the extra 4 bytes.  Why would you be indexing such a large column?

Comment: @jdweng The limits for column size aren't the same as the limits for index size. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: kindly see the below 2 links......https://ibb.co/d9X0dH

https://ibb.co/gauDyH

Comment: `SELECT * FROM CompanyInfo WHERE DATALENGTH(exblist) > 900` should give you back the offending row(s).

Comment: @chetankambli Please include the images in the question, not in a comment that is too easy to miss

Comment: Possible duplicate of [900 byte index size limit in character length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717317/900-byte-index-size-limit-in-character-length)

Comment: @mjwills...if i removed include part also,it gives me the same error...

Comment: Please run `sp_help dbo.companyinfo` and update your post with the result.

Comment: Try posting the schema of table as text and the repro steps

Comment: You should really look into how to design a database. Based on your column names and types, it looks like several of your columns contain some sort of comma etc. separated lists. That's going to be awful to manage & query.

Comment: @mjwills...i updated...kindly check the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Based on SQL Server documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241(v=sql.105).aspx), `nvarchar(450)` should work.

I do find the "904" to be confusing.  The actual size of `nvarchar(450)` is 902 bytes (see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939(v=sql.110).aspx)).  No doubt, the extra two bytes are coming from somewhere.

So, you should be able to fix this by using `nvarchar(448)`.

If that is not possible, you can add another column and index that:

```
alter t add exblist448 as (left(exblist, 1, 448))
```

and then index this.

All that said, I don't think this will solve your *real* problem.  I don't see why an index on a 450-character string would be needed.  I also don't understand why a column name would contain "list".

I strongly suspect that you really need either a second table with one row per list item and company.  Or, you need a full text index.

Comment: ...when i am trying to insert some emailids it throws out that error with different numbers..sometimes it is 904...sometimes its is 908..depending upon the entered emailids..For some entered emailids it is inserting fine...

Comment: @chetankambli . . . As suspected.  First, you don't really want to put email ids into a single column.  A separate table with one row per email id would be the correct approach.  Second, an index on the column is not going to be very helpful.

Comment: @Gordon...If i am removing that index(i.e.IX_companyinfo_exhibition), then that error should not have come...right?

Comment: @gordon....https://ibb.co/hMwWkx....... this is the link from where i entered emailid (i.e. info@pakona.com),and then i clicked on save button and then i got error that "904 exceeds size limit 900"....so if i removing na or a from info@pakona.com..it is saving and not throwing that error...

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually i already mentioned that to him on his first question https://stackoverflow.com/a/48878560/2705620

Comment: @GordonLinoff...i removed that index....and it worked perfectly for me...thank u so much...:)