# How to redefine slow SQL query with COUNT() of large dataset in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, count

I have a SQL query like this and I would need to redefine it or using indexes would help I believe, but I do not know which columns include into indexes.

- `b_answers` has approx. tens of thousand of rows
- `b_projects` has approx. thousands of rows
- `b_users` has tens of rows

These `AS count_*` columns are needed for sorting.

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.datetime,
    u.name AS u_name,
    p.name,
    p.note,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND  changed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND started = '1') AS count_started,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id) AS count_sent,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '1' AND  changed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled_quiz1_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '2' AND  changed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled_quiz1_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '1' AND started = '1') AS count_started_quiz1_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '2' AND started = '1') AS count_started_quiz1_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '1') AS count_sent_quiz1_a
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '2') AS count_sent_quiz1_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '3' AND  changed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled_quiz3_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '4' AND  changed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled_quiz3_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '3' AND started = '1') AS count_started_quiz3_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '4' AND started = '1') AS count_started_quiz3_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '3') AS count_sent_quiz3_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '4') AS count_sent_quiz3_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '5' AND  changed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled_quiz5_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '6' AND  changed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled_quiz5_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '5' AND started = '1') AS count_started_quiz5_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '6' AND started = '1') AS count_started_quiz5_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '5') AS count_sent_quiz5_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '6') AS count_sent_quiz5_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '7' AND  changed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled_quiz7_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '8' AND  changed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled_quiz7_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '7' AND started = '1') AS count_started_quiz7_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '8' AND started = '1') AS count_started_quiz7_b,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '7') AS count_sent_quiz7_a,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM b_answers WHERE project = t.id AND quiz = '8') AS count_sent_quiz7_b
FROM 
    b_projects p
LEFT JOIN 
    b_answers a ON a.project = p.id
LEFT JOIN 
    b_users u ON u.id = p.admin
GROUP BY
    p.nazev
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: MySQL, sorry for missing that, I fill in that already.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation!  The idea is:

```
SELECT p.id, p.datetime, u.name AS u_name, p.name, p.note,
       SUM(a.changed <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled,
       SUM(a.started = '1') AS count_started,
       . . .   -- and so one for the rest of the columns
FROM b_projects p LEFT JOIN 
     b_answers a 
     ON a.project = p.id LEFT JOIN 
     b_users u
     ON u.id = p.admin
GROUP BY p.id, p.datetime, u.name, p.name, p.note
```

Comment: Caution -- The JOINs may inflate the SUMs.

Comment: @RickJames . . . Although possible that seems unlikely.  The `join` from `b_projects` to `b_users` would appear to be to (at most) one user.  And it is a fair guess that `p_projects.id` is the primary key in that table.

Comment: Well, this works, but it is still very slow. Query takes tens of seconds, with the half of data set, for the first time. Next time it is fast, but it is caused by cache I believe.

Comment: Now, I've added indexes to columns `a.changed`, `a.started`, `a.project`, `a.quiz`, `p.admin` and now it takes approx 2 sec, but still I would like to increase the speed. I've read the article linked below, about the indexes, but I now I have no idea how to create indexes differently.

Comment: @sylar32 . . . I am guessing you have a lot of data -- and the `group by` is going to eat up the time.  I don't see how those indexes would help.  Indexes on `a(pid) and `u(admin)` might help.  You can add additional columns based on what is referenced in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Just not to reinvent wheel !!! please see this.
[What columns generally make good indexes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107132/what-columns-generally-make-good-indexes)

Indexes are generally required in columns used to compare (conditions). 
so in your case, I think indexes which can be used to improve COST would include columns in this part of the query.

> LEFT JOIN    b_answers a ON a.project = p.id /* consider to use index
>   */
>
> LEFT JOIN 
>       b_users u ON u.id = p.admin /* consider to use index */
>
> GROUP BY
>       p.nazev /* consider to use index  - STILL UNSURE*/

you can check the effects of the query with trial and error.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To get the query right, you need to take into consideration whether the tables are in a 1:many mapping.  If so, do you want the count to be "many" or just "1"

I will assume you don't want inflated values, so I will get the counts in a derived table *first*, then join to the other table(s):

```
SELECT  p.id, p.datetime, u.name AS u_name, p.name, p.note,
        count_filled, count_started, ...
    FROM  
        ( SELECT
                SUM(a.changed <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00') AS count_filled,
                SUM(a.started = '1') AS count_started,
                ...
            FROM  b_answers AS a 
        ) AS aa
    JOIN  b_projects p  ON aa.project = p.id
    LEFT JOIN  b_users u  ON u.id = p.admin
```

Note that this avoids the `GROUP BY`, thereby providing one speedup.  The other is avoiding the "inflate-deflate".

Assuming `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table, no extra indexes are needed.