# SQL query with multiple joins to the same table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a query (simplified to show the problem, but remove 7 more similar joins):

```
SELECT 
    `s`.`id`, `s`.`mobile_number`, MAX(`s`.`row_number`), `s`.`campaign_name`, `s`.`createdate`, `s`.`moddate`, 
    `se1`.`column_value` AS `first_name`, 
    `se2`.`column_value` AS `last_name`
FROM `kcms_shopper` `s`
LEFT JOIN `kcms_shopper_extend` `se1` 
    ON `s`.`mobile_number` = `se1`.`mobile_number` 
    AND `s`.`campaign_name` = `se1`.`campaign_name`
    AND `s`.`row_number` = `se1`.`row_number`
LEFT JOIN `kcms_shopper_extend` `se2` 
    ON `s`.`mobile_number` = `se2`.`mobile_number` 
    AND `s`.`campaign_name` = `se2`.`campaign_name`
    AND `s`.`row_number` = `se1`.`row_number`
WHERE `s`.`row_number` = (
    SELECT MAX(`row_number`) 
    FROM `kcms_shopper_extend` sx 
    WHERE `s`.`mobile_number` = `sx`.`mobile_number`
    AND `s`.`campaign_name` = `sx`.`campaign_name`
)
AND `se1`.`column_name` = "first_name"
AND `se2`.`column_name` = "last_name"
GROUP BY `s`.`mobile_number`, `s`.`row_number`
ORDER BY `s`.`mobile_number` ASC
```

Where the goal is to get data from table `shopper` and joining multiple times on `shopper_extend`.

Each `shopper` can have multiple rows (if they entered a campaign more than once using their mobile number) and each campaign can have a custom configured set of columns captured per campaign, hence the join table.

The structure of `shopper` is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `kcms_shopper` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `mobile_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `campaign_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `row_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `createdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `moddate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `kcms_shopper`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ADD KEY `ix__mobile_number` (`mobile_number`) USING BTREE,
    ADD KEY `ix__campaign_name` (`campaign_name`);

ALTER TABLE `kcms_shopper`
    MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

The structure of `shopper_extend` is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `kcms_shopper_extend` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `shopper_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `mobile_number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    `campaign_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `row_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `column_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    `column_value` varchar(4096) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `kcms_shopper_extend`
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ADD KEY `ix__column_name` (`column_name`) USING BTREE,
    ADD KEY `ix__mobile_number` (`mobile_number`),
    ADD KEY `ix__campaign_name` (`campaign_name`);

ALTER TABLE `kcms_shopper_extend`
    MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Please assist me in retrieving:

```
1. The last entry of a user (row_number)
2. For a specific campaign
3. Using a specific mobile number
```

The above query does not result in an error (yet), but I believe it to be wrong, because it does not complete. It hangs my MySQL for at least 10 minutes (by the time of completing this question, the query has not yet completed.

Comment: One of the reasons it's probably taking so long is I don't see an `INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY` on the `CREATE` statement(s) ..  You should be adding an `INDEX` for any field you will be explicitly searching (`WHERE` clause) by or fields being compared with the `ON` clause a `JOIN` statement.

Comment: In case I was correct in you not having indexed fields -- Read the top answer on [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107132/what-columns-generally-make-good-indexes) to better explain why and what it means.

Comment: Hi @Zac,  I do have indexes and primary keys. I omitted them them from the structure posted, as they were exported as separate queries (ALTER TABLE) and I did not believe that it added value, but I see now that it does add value. I will amend the question.

Comment: In the future, when asking questions about query optimization, please do include the index and key definitions. Readers will always ask for them, and knowing what indexes currently exist in your tables will help us understand what needs to be done for further optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have no indexes defined in your tables. (Edit: since your initial post of this question, you updated it with indexes.)

Indexes are important for optimizing joins. You can verify whether a query uses indexes by analyzing the query with EXPLAIN.

I tested your query with EXPLAIN and found it was doing joins "the hard way" which is indicated by "Using join buffer (hash join)". (Edit: I first tested the query against tables with no indexes, as they were initially described.)

Also the subquery is a "Dependent Subquery" which means it must be executed many times, once for each distinct value it is compared to in the outer query. This is very expensive for performance.

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | se1   | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 |    25.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | s     | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 |    33.33 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)   |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | se2   | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 |    25.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join)   |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | sx    | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    4 |    25.00 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I then created some indexes I thought would help:

```
ALTER TABLE kcms_shopper
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
    ADD INDEX bk1 (`row_number`),
    ADD INDEX bk2 (`mobile_number`, `campaign_name`, `row_number`);

ALTER TABLE kcms_shopper_extend
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (id),
    ADD INDEX bk3 (mobile_number, campaign_name, `row_number`, column_name);
```

And I refactored your subquery into another OUTER JOIN. I've used this method to implement the greatest-row-per-group type of query pattern. This allows the join to be optimized with indexes, just like any other join.

```
SELECT
    `s`.`id`,
    `s`.`mobile_number`,
    MAX(`s`.`row_number`),
    `s`.`campaign_name`,
    `s`.`createdate`,
    `s`.`moddate`,
    `se1`.`column_value` AS `first_name`,
    `se2`.`column_value` AS `last_name`
FROM `kcms_shopper` `s`
LEFT JOIN `kcms_shopper_extend` `se1`
    ON `s`.`mobile_number` = `se1`.`mobile_number`
    AND `s`.`campaign_name` = `se1`.`campaign_name`
    AND `s`.`row_number` = `se1`.`row_number`
LEFT JOIN `kcms_shopper_extend` `se2`
    ON `s`.`mobile_number` = `se2`.`mobile_number`
    AND `s`.`campaign_name` = `se2`.`campaign_name`
    AND `s`.`row_number` = `se2`.`row_number`
LEFT JOIN `kcms_shopper` `sx`
    ON `s`.`mobile_number` = `sx`.`mobile_number`
    AND `s`.`campaign_name` = `sx`.`campaign_name`
    AND `s`.`row_number` < `sx`.`row_number`
WHERE `sx`.`row_number` IS NULL
AND `se1`.`column_name` = "first_name"
AND `se2`.`column_name` = "last_name"
GROUP BY `s`.`mobile_number`, `s`.`row_number`
ORDER BY `s`.`mobile_number` ASC;
```

The EXPLAIN analysis shows that it uses indexes for all the joins. It still has to do a table-scan for the first table, but the others are all resolved with indexed lookups (indicated by `type: ref` in the EXPLAIN report).

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref                                           | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | se1   | NULL       | ALL  | bk3           | NULL | NULL    | NULL                                          |    4 |    25.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | NULL       | ref  | bk1,bk2       | bk1  | 4       | test.se1.row_number                           |    1 |    25.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | se2   | NULL       | ref  | bk3           | bk3  | 324     | test.se1.mobile_number,test.se1.campaign_name |    1 |    25.00 | Using index condition                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sx    | NULL       | ref  | bk1,bk2       | bk2  | 66      | test.se1.mobile_number                        |    1 |    25.00 | Using where; Not exists; Using index         |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-----------------------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU)
 of me presenting it.

I also wrote a chapter on indexing in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: Thank you. I have changed my indexes to the way you made them, and used your query, and I am now getting FAST results. Awesome. I will read through your article, and understand your query before continuing to use it - it is the least I can do :-) Thank you again!

Comment: For more explanation of how the join finds the greatest value, see for example my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/123481/20860

Comment: OK, so from your presentation, I have learned a lot about indexing. I will have to play around with my indexes after bringing back the other 7 joins I have removed before, but for all practical reasons this is working. Thank you again!

Comment: I see in the second left join (se2) you are referencing se1's row number. Is that a typo, or intentional?

Comment: And the last join (sx), you match mobile_number twice. Suspecting that should be `campaign_name` there? Sorry - not intending to point out possible errors in your answer, I simply am not sure if that was intentional.

Comment: Thanks, those are copy & paste mistakes, I've edited to fix them. I re-ran the test after fixing the mistakes, and confirmed it does not affect the indexes MySQL chooses in this case.

Comment: @KobusMyburgh -- My comment to you was about indexes **and** keys --  Your alter statements only include keys with no indexes ..  Bills answer here was what I was trying to nudge you to go find the answer.  Lead a horse to water sort of thing :)